# How to read a password which has special characters from property file in Mule 3?

Tags: passwords, mule, special-characters, mulesoft

I have a below password which has special characters, When I am trying to read in mule 3 as ${inter.password} it is giving me an error as it couldn't read password. I tried it by keeping \ before the special character in passwprd, but I am still getting same error.

inter.password=  =Vem}zt@S7Qe\9FZ

Comment: In which component or configuration are you using the password? Also please share the complete and exact error.

Comment: Its a SOAP webservice password. I am trying to configure this in web service consumer for authentication.

Comment: Please share the XML configuration and the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this problem in Mule 3 transport configurations, the value has to be encoded with [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). You can use Java, Groovy or most programming languages to obtain the encoded. There are online encoders/decoders but I would not put sensitive information like a password in a public online service.

Example in Groovy command line:

```
$ groovy -e "println URLEncoder.encode('this%is@test')"
this%25is%40test
```

Source: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-URL-Encode-special-characters-in-transport-endpoint-URLs